# unable to open url: tel xxx by Linking.openURL(jumpUrl) in ios 10

Tags: react-native, ios10, openurl

When I code in my xxx.tsx file with the below content:

```
const jumpUrl = "tel:" + mobileNumber;
Linking.openURL(jumpUrl);
```

After then, In our crash monitor website, I found that the MRN crash occurred in iOS 10.3.3 device:
**Unable to open URL: tel:xxx**, so I want to know how to fix it